# Create local notification and fire at certain time every day (Swift)

Tags: swift, uilocalnotification

Sorry if this is a duplicate, but I couldn't find this question for swift.

I need to create a local notification that fires everyday at 7.00 AM. I think the user has to go on the app at least once for the notification to start, so after they have launched the app, they never have to go on it again and the notification just fires everyday automatically.

How do I do this in Swift?

Comment: Look at this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31567984/how-to-put-notifications-on-ios-application-to-repeat-every-one-1-hour/

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. That is how you repeat a notification every 1 hour, not how to set it to repeat from a certain time, in my case, 7.00 AM.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to create local notifications in iphone app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047117/how-to-create-local-notifications-in-iphone-app)

Comment: You can find a tutorial in an already answered question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047117/how-to-create-local-notifications-in-iphone-app

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31567984/how-to-put-notifications-on-ios-application-to-repeat-every-one-1-hour/

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but:

```
var dateComponent = DateComponents()
dateComponent.hour = 7
dateComponent.minute = 0

let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponent, repeats: true)
```